# Remove selected option from another select box doesnt work on phone

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to remove or hide the select option if it was selected before.
the code works on desktop, but on mobile it doesn't.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').on('change', function(event) {
        var prevValue = $(this).data('previous');
        $('select')
            .not(this)
            .find('option[value="' + prevValue + '"]')
            .show();
        var value = $(this).val();
        $(this).data('previous', value);
        $('select')
            .not(this)
            .find('option[value="' + value + '"]')
            .hide();
    });
});
```

Thanks..

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+nearest+OR+closest+date+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Might be good to check the event trigger on Mobile. Sometimes, mobile browsers might handle events differently. You can test this by adding a console.log('Change event triggered'); within the event handler to see if it's being executed.